# How to insert new value into array as per key value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need one help. I need to insert one new value into existing array by matching the key value using Javascript.I am explaining the scenario below.

```
var galArr=[
     {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'13.png','comment':'hello','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee','act':'edit'},
]
```

The above is my existing array.I need to match with the below another array.

```
var arr=[
    {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii'},
    {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee'},
]
```

Here i need to match the array `arr` with an array `galArr` if image name will same this `checked:true` will add in the rective row of existing array `galArr`. Suppose `arr[0].image==galArr[0].image` then `checked:true` will add in that respective row of existing array. Please help me.

Comment: I would check my answer and the updated I did some minutes ago, because your selected answer may hurt performance if our gallery array contains a lot of elements. Check the *set* part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be sufficient.

```js
var galArr=[
     {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'13.png','comment':'hello','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee','act':'edit'},
];
var arr=[
    {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii'},
    {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee'},
];

// start looping over `arr`
arr.forEach(function(o, i){
   
  // now loop over `galArr` to find match
  galArr.forEach(function(gO, i){
      // when there is a match
      if(o.image == gO.image){
         console.log(gO);
         // add checked property to this object
         gO['checked'] = true;
      }
  });
  
});

// Output
console.log(galArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all check condition and if the condition match then create a new temp json and replace it with old json

```
 arr.forEach(function(d){
       galArr.forEach(function(e){
            if(e.image==d.image){
               temp = {};
               temp.image = e.image;
               temp.comment = e.comment;
               temp.checked = e.comment;
               temp.action = e.action;
               e = temp;
            }
       });
    });
```

Comment: You should add an explanation as to what your code is doing - adding just code is not a good way to answer a question

Answer (score 0):

I would create an image index, where its indexes would be the whole image file names and later I would use that image index to quickly check and add `checked` property to `galArr` array:

```js
var galArr=[
     {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'13.png','comment':'hello','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee','act':'edit'},
];
  
var imageIndex = galArr.map(function(item) {
    return item.image;
});

var arr=[
    {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii'},
    {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee'},
]

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.checked = imageIndex.indexOf(item.image) > -1;
});
```

If your users will use your JavaScript code within a modern Web browser, I would use the new [`Set` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
var galArr=[
     {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'13.png','comment':'hello','act':'edit'},
     {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee','act':'edit'},
];
  
var imageIndex = galArr.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result.add(item.image);
 
    return result;
}, new Set());

var arr=[
    {'image':'12.png','comment':'hii'},
    {'image':'14.png','comment':'hee'},
]

arr.forEach(function(item) {
    item.checked = imageIndex.has(item.image);
});
```

I've asked a question to assist everyone in understanding how valueable are *sets*: [Is Set a hashed collection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39763008/is-set-a-hashed-collection-in-javascript/39763170#39763170)